# Assembler - trouble with arrays

Tags: assembly, integer, cpu-registers, dword

I have some problem with code in assembler which is responsible for copying one array into other (arrays of integers).

This is how I create arrays in c++:

```
int *myArray=new int[myFunctions::getCounter()];
int *newArray;
int *newArray = new int[counter+1]; // I have some information in [0]
```

And this is how I declare assembler's function

```
extern int  copy(myArray[], int *newArray, int howManyElements, int howManyProcesses, int indexOfProcess);
```

About processes: This is part of the project. Procedure (in loop) works like that:

In example we have 3 processes and 10 elements in array

1st process copied into new array elements: [1] [4] [7] [10]
2nd [2] [5] [8] 3rd [3] [6] [9]

In c++ :

```
for (int i=indexOfProcess; i<=howManyElements; i+=howManyProcess){

        newArray[i]  = myArray[i];

    }
```

In c++ it works fine. In assembler I have trouble. Only first element is copied properly. Rest of elements are unchanged. 
MASM Code:

```html
copy proc uses ebx ecx edx esi edi myArray:DWORD, newArray:DWORD, howManyElements:DWORD, howManyProcesses:DWORD, indexOfProcess:DWORD
 
 
 
 
local ahowManyProcesses:DWORD 
local ahowManyElements:DWORD              
 
local  adressOfArray:DWORD
 
mov eax, howManyElements          
mov ahowManyElements, eax     
mov eax, howManyProcesses          
mov ahowManyProcesses, eax    
 
 
xor eax, eax            
 
mov ecx, indexOfProcess          
mov ebx, myArray       
mov edx, newArray   
mov adressOfTab, edx
 
 
add ebx, ecx               
add edx, ecx               
add eax, ecx                   
 
 
loop:
mov eax, [ebx]           
mov [edx], eax          
add ebx, ahowManyProcesses 
add edx, ahowManyProcesses
add eax, ahowManyProcesses
 
 
cmp eax, ahowManyElements 
jbe loop                              
 
 
 
mov eax, adressOfArray
ret
 
copy endp
 
end
```

For example:

> myArray [1] = 10 [2] = 11 [3] = 3 [4] = 13...
>
> newArray before procedure [1] = 0 [2] = 0 [3] = 0 [4] = 0...
>
> newArray after procedure [1] = 10 [2] = 0 [3] = 0 [4] = 0...

I think there is some problem with DWORD/BYTE. I tried change ecx to [ecx+4] and other combinations but I don't know how to repair code.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have at least two problems. One, you are not scaling for integer size. You have to increment your pointers by 4 times the number of items. The other problem is you are trying to use `eax` for loop counter, but at the same time you also use it as a temporary for the copy, so you overwrite your counter.

```
mov ecx, indexOfProcess          
mov ebx, myArray       
mov edx, newArray   
mov adressOfTab, edx

lea ebx, [ebx+ecx*4]       ; scale by 4 for int size
lea edx, [edx+ecx*4]       ; scale by 4 for int size

loop:
mov eax, [ebx]
mov [edx], eax
mov eax, ahowManyProcesses ; the increment in items
lea ebx, [ebx+eax*4]       ; scale by 4 for int size
lea edx, [edx+eax*4]       ; scale by 4 for int size
add ecx, eax               ; do not scale, it is a counter

cmp ecx, ahowManyElements 
jbe loop
```

PS: You should learn to use a debugger so you can fix your own mistakes.